# Working with TypeScript in Visual Studio, randomly causes errors in lib.d.ts and restart needed

Tags: visual-studio-2012, typescript

I am working in visual studio 12 and 13. In both cases after some random amount of time 100 errors comes up in lib.d.ts and intellisense stops working ect. Everything compiles fine.

Restarting VS, things work fine again.

Are there any logs for the tsc compiler that I can inspect? I feel that I sometimes need to use commandline to compile with tsc and things work, where VS sometimes generate javascript files where imported modules are missing (using AMD generation).

It also happens that it sets the imported module **modulename** = 'thenameandpath', and then when manually doing tsc, no problems.

Comment: Try uninstalling web essentials. And reinstalling typescript

Comment: Its a brand new pc, only the latest version of webessensial and typescript have been installed. Should i run without webessensials ? or was your sugesstion based on old version might be doing something?

Comment: I will try to remove it and see if it resolves anything. But as only the latest version have been installed, I am not sure if it helps.  Are there not some logs in VS that I can browse and maybe find something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typescript 0.95 solved most of this issues.
Try to upgrade.